# iPhone - removing an entire viewController, not just its view

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm not using a navigation controller or a tab bar controller, I'm not using the push/pop method or presenting views modally. In my main view controller, I am adding a view controller like so:

```
UIViewController *nextController;
nextController = [[GamePlayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GamePlayView" bundle:nil];
[nextController performSelector:@selector(setDelegate:) withObject:self];

temporaryController = nextController;

[self.view addSubview:nextController.view];
```

This view controller follows a delegate protocol and when the user is finished in this game view, this code is called:

```
[delegate backToMenu:self];
```

which calls this function in the app's main view controller:

```
- (void)backToMenu:(GamePlayViewController *)sender {
    NSLog(@"back to menu");

    [temporaryController.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Removing the view with removeFromSuperview seems to get rid of the view only, but I can see due to NSLogging that code is still executing in the .m file of that removed view. The view is still in in the app's memory. It has not been discarded as I had hoped.

"Release" is an old relic never to be used with ARC, so how can I entirely remove the viewController that was created with alloc/initWithNibName?

Thanks!

Comment: How is `temporaryController` defined?  If it's a strong property, the answer may be as simple as setting it to nil.

Comment: @PhillipMills it is declared in my main view controller's header file: UIViewController *temporaryController; Setting it to nil was tried as part of the solution Rich provided below, but didn't change how that view still continues to run code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also be using the view controller life cycle methods.

Adding:

```
GamePlayViewController *nextController = [[GamePlayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GamePlayView" bundle:nil];
nextController.delegate = self;
[self addChildViewController:nextController];
[self.view addSubview:nextController.view];
[nextController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

temporaryController = nextController;
```

Removing:

```
[temporaryController didMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[temporaryController.view removeFromSuperview];
[temporaryController removeFromParentViewController];
temporaryController = nil;
```

Also if `temporaryController` is a strong property (or you've used an iVar), you should `nil` it out after removing it.

As the `CAAnimation` retains its delegate make you remove the animation and `nil` out the delegate.

```
-(void)didMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parentViewController
{
    [super didMoveToParentViewController:parentViewController];

    if (!parentViewController) {
        CAAnimation *animation = [movingObject.layer animationForKey:@"animatePositionX"];
        animation.delegate = nil;
        [movingObject.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"animatePositionX"];
    }
}
```

If you want to check your view controller is being deallocoated you should implement the `dealloc` method and place a breakpoint inside of it. I suggest a breakpoint over a `NSLog` as I don't know how much you already log out so it might get missed, with a breakpoint it is much clearly - actually stopping the program flow.

Comment: @ObjectiveFlash I've updated to add some more context to the code with regards to your question.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer me. After changing the code to be like what you have shown here, I still get code executing on the viewController that has been removedFromSuperview and removedFromParentViewController and set equal to nil. Somehow the viewController remains active though its view is gone.

Comment: Are you keeping a reference to it anywhere else? Are you using it as a delegate anywhere and the delegate property isn't declared as `weak`?
How are you checking its still 'active' - by a breakpoint in the `dealloc` method?

Comment: I have an animation in the GamePlay view that repeats with an NSLog each time. After the view has been removed, this code continues to run and print out NSLog statements. The GamePlay.h has a @protocol GameDelegate / id <GameDelegate> __unsafe_unretained delegate; / property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) id <GameDelegate> delegate; which is synthesized in the .m implementation and allows me to call functions back in the root view controller. It is also a delegate itself: interface GamePlayViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate, UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate> {

Comment: How do you do the animation?

Comment: It's a CABasicAnimation that gets called on a layer in the GameView with [movingObject.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animatePositionX"] and then in the -(void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag { section I am calling either [self beginAnimate] or [self beginAnimate2] to run the animation again in the opposite direction

Comment: `CAAnimation` and its subclass `CABasicAnimation` retain their delegates as per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CAAnimation/delegate) this is why its not being dealloced, I'll update my answer with some code.

Comment: Sorry Rich, but I'm still not there. The line "animation.delegate = nil" causes a SIGABRT crash. I've also tried a different approach without the animation. I created this function: - (void) startMove {
    NSLog(@"GONNA MOVE");
    [self performSelector:@selector(startMove) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5]; } and I see that it too continues to run after being removed and set to nil, even with your code of chid and parent view controllers. No animation. View removed and set to nil. And it's still running the code in .m implementation...

Comment: @ObjectiveFlash, what code is still running in the .m? Do you have a timer or something set up that you can see running?

Comment: Yes, it prints "GONNA MOVE" every 0.5 seconds which is set with a  [self performSelector:@selector(startMove) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5]; inside of the startMove function in an endless loop. I created this just to test whether the .m code was still running. I thought it would cease to run when the view was removed, yet it continues to run.

Comment: I know I can play around with [self.view.layer removeAllAnimations] for animations and [cancelPreviousPerformRequests] to stop timed selector calls, but the fact that code is still running at all bugs me, as I would prefer to remove the view entirely from the app's running memory. If I open the GamePlay view again from the main menu, and alloc initWithNib that view just like I did the first time, do I now have TWO instances of it? If they return to the main menu and choose to play the game again, are there now THREE instances running? How do I entirely remove the viewControllers I created?

Comment: @ObjectiveFlash, your test is the problem. Using a performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: prevents the controller from being deallocated!

Comment: @ObjectiveFlash, performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: sets up a timer, and a timer keeps a strong reference to its target (which will be your controller), so that's why your controller never gets deallocated. Instead of using this to check whether your controller is still alive, just implement dealloc, and put a log in it. I think you'll find that the code in this answer will cause your controller to be deallocated.

Comment: Okay... thank you both so much! Implementing NSLog in dealloc really helps to understand this. I see that ongoing timers/selector calls prevent a view from deallocing which was my real issue. As for using alloc/addSubview vs alloc/addChild/addSubview/didMoveToParent - I don't see any difference in how they affect dealloc or anything else. As for removing the CAAnimation, I simply called [movingObject.layer removeAllAnimations] before calling the [delegate backToMenu]; Also noticed that temporaryController = nil will dealloc immediately, w/out it the view deallocs next time the variable is used

Comment: Not sure whether to mark this as the correct answer?  The final answer to my question after all your help is that any CAAnimations or performSelector/timers will prevent a view from deallocing. Also that setting temporaryController = nil will dealloc a view controller immediately (if no timers/CAAnimations) as opposed to just calling removeFromSuperview which will dealloc when the variable is needed again. Also the note that implementing dealloc itself and setting an NSLog in there is an extremely helpful bit.

Comment: What is good stackoverflow protocol for marking this question solved? You guys really helped me a lot! thanks again!

Comment: @ObjectiveFlash You can accept the answer I suppose as its got some good info in it. I'll move my "breakpoint in `dealloc`" into the answer too :)